# What is wrong with my eslintrc parser options? SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Tags: javascript, eslint, lint

```
{
    "parserOptions" : {
        "ecmaVersion": 2017
    },

    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "node": true,
      "es6": true
    },
   }

module.exports = { "extends": "plugin:prettier/recommended" };
```

When I try

```
eslint test.js
```

I got this error

```
/home/miki/azatmardan/ch8/new-restexpress/.eslintrc.js:2
    "parserOptions" : {
                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
```

This
[image]

How to format `.eslinterc`?

Comment: Maybe the `,` after the `env` object. Could you please try to remove it?

Comment: The same, unfortunately.

Comment: "I looked at oher SO questions before choosing this" is not a useful statement. If there are other questions that provide context then tell us what those questions are!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JavaScript is not valid.

You appear to be starting by having an object:

> ```
> {
>     "parserOptions" : {
> ```
>
> etc

But because you have *just* thrown an object into the file without putting any context (such as a variable assignment first) it is a syntax error.

It looks like you've mixed up the syntax of `.eslintrc.js` and `.eslintrc.json`.

---

Then, you continue with:

> ```
> module.exports = { "extends": "plugin:prettier/recommended" };
> ```

… which completely ignores that object.

---

You need a *single* object which you can then either export from a JS file or just have in a JSON file.

## .eslintrc.json

```
{
    "extends": "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2017
    },
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true,
        "es6": true
    }
}
```

## .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
    "extends": "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2017
    },
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true,
        "es6": true
    }
}
```